# Complete an URL with the name of the file inside the folder

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I complete this URL knowing that I don't know the name and the extension of the file ?

I use window.open (javascript)

```js
window.open('cartes_identites/'+recto+'_recto/?.?');
```

where the firt ? is the name of the file and the second is the extension like :

dupont.pdf

I have only one file in the folder, I will always have ONLY one file.

This is my whole code :

```js
$('#img_recto').click(function(){
        var recto = $("select[name='liste_non_agree'] > option:selected").text();
        window.open('cartes_identites/'+recto+'_recto/');
    });
```

Comment: Based on client side Javascript alone, I do not think this is possible, as it does not have access to server side folders. This can only be achieved on the server side.

Comment: The browser doesn't have access to the file system, so you can't query the files like in a normal desktop application

Comment: Thank you.  I just thought like you a minute ago... Maybe I will use ajax and scandir() in php.